# SSH connection in Amazon EC2 crashes after a while

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am testing the free services from Amazon EC2. I followed the manual and was able to access the server. After one minute inside the server, it crashes and I have to close my console and reboot the instance.

By reading the guides from Amazon, I found that I should set the Route Table, which I was not able to find. Maybe the dashboard has changed.

Comment: do you mean route 53???

Comment: no, I am not using route 53. I just want to use the server to perform some computations through ssh.